# Obtain values of a section of a file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a configuration file in the following format.

```
<Title>
 [part1]
  A.File = a
  A.Val = val1
  B.File = a
  B.Val = val1
 [part2]
  A.File = a1
  A.Val = val2 
  B.File = a
  B.Val = val1
```

I want to extract values from first part only.

```
 #!/bin/sh 
getCalibDate()
{
 file="/path/of/config/file"
 value=`cat ${file} | grep Val | cut -d'=' -f2`
    for v in $value
    do
            echo $v
    done
}
getCalibDate
```

Above script will return all the values.
How can I get values from only first part (part1) ?

Comment: Note that `cat file | grep foo` is pointless. It's known as a ["useless use of cat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat). You can always do `grep foo file` instead.

Comment: Saying `${file}` instead of just plain `$file` is occasionally useful, but it’s much more useful to get into the habit of saying `"$file"`. Saying `${file}` will not protect you against having space or wildcard characters in `$file`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have only 4 lines after `[part1]` you can use `-A4` option with `grep`:

```
cat ${file} | grep -A4 "part1" | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

For general case (more than 4 lines after [part1]) use `sed` to get the text between two parts:

```
cat ${file} | sed -n "/part1/,/part2/p" | head -n-1
```

`head` is to delete additional `part2` at the end

As [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) said you don't have to use `cat`, you can do the following instead:

```
grep -A4 "part1" ${file} | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

OR:

```
sed -n "/part1/,/part2/p" ${file} | head -n-1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a more sophisticated tool to parse the file. For example, `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh 

getCalibDate()
{
 file="${1}"
 value=$(awk  '/\[part/{a++}(a<2 && /Val/){print $NF}' ${file})

    for v in $value
    do
            echo $v
    done
}

getCalibDate ${1}
```

Here, the variable `a` is incremented each time a line matches `[part`. Then, the last field (`$NF`) is printed when a line matches `Val` but only if `a` is less than 2, only if we're in the 1st section.

Comment: `awk` is just an amazing tool

Comment: @Networker yeah. It's a full programming language, there are some very very complex programs written in `awk`. One of the first gene prediction algorithms for example.

Comment: The question says `cut -d'=' -f2`, which yields the second `=`-delimited field. Your answer yields the last space-delimited field. They are the same for the sample data in the question, but it is *sample* data. I wonder what the real data look like.

Comment: @G-Man true. I had originally written `awk -F= '{print $2}'` which does the same thing but I felt that `$NF` was simpler in this case.

Comment: @terdon: Gene prediction?? That's a little bit... awk

Answer (score 2):

and use this:

```
sed -n -e '/\[part1\]/,/\[part2\]/p' FILE |sed -e '1d;$d'| awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

OUTPUT is:

```
 a
 val1
 a
 val1
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the whole lines from the first part:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\[/ {n++;next} n==1'
```

To just print the right hand side of the first `=`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\[/ {n++;next} n==1 {sub(/^[^=]*=[[:blank:]]*/,""); print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers here,
but I see only one that incorporates the `Val` part of the problem,
and it’s ambiguous whether that is correct. 
I agree that `awk` is “an amazing tool”, but it’s not necessary here;
I believe that this `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/\[part1\]/,/\[part2\]/s/.*Val.*=//p' "$file"
```

probably does what’s desired. 
Like the other `sed -e '/\[part1\]/,/\[part2\]/p'` solutions
([Networker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151581/80216)
and [Babyy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151587/80216)),
this is trivially adaptable to select any section. 
(You do, of course, need to know its name; if you know only its ordinal number,
you can adapt [terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151582/80216)
or [glenn jackman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151596/80216),
both of which *count* sections rather than looking for a specific name.) 
If you don’t know the name of section following, you can do

```
sed -n '/\[part42\]/,/\[part/s…' "$file"
```

for example.

My only meta-question is regarding the `cut -d'=' -f2` part of the question. 
If an input line that we’re extracting data from contains multiple `=` characters
after `Val` (i.e., the field value contains `=` character(s)), e.g.,

```
Einstein.Val = E=mc^2
```

then the above `cut` command will extract only the text between the first and second `=`
(i.e., the field value, up to (but not including) the first `=`), e.g.,  `E`. 
The `sed` command I have presented above will extract only the text
after the *last* `=` (e.g., `mc^2`). 
To get everything after the first `=` (e.g., `E=mc^2`), use

```
sed -n '/\[part1\]/,/\[part2\]/s/.*Val[^=]*=//p' "$file"
```

To mimic the behavior of the `cut` (e.g.,  `E`), use

```
sed -n '/\[part1\]/,/\[part2\]/s/.*Val[^=]*=\([^=]*\).*/\1/p' "$file"
```

---

Note that my approach assumes that the data look
at least generally like the illustration in the question;
i.e., at least one `=` appears somewhere to the right of the `Val` string. 
Accordingly, all of my solutions will ignore input like

```
Girl.Name = Valerie
Valerie Bertinelli
```

even if it falls between `[part1]` and `[part2]`.

Comment: Your last thing does not mimic the behavior of cut. If `cut` splits on equals and prints only the second field of the line, and - as I think you're trying to suggest - there are more than matching fields then yours old handles the problem of the *last* three matching fields. And this is how your command does not mimic `cut`.

Comment: @mikeserv: Huh? What?

Comment: just what i said - It does not mimic cut because  you do `s/.*`... Doing that means it will only get the last possible occurrence of `Val[^=]*=\([^=]*\).*/\1`. Seems like you worked it up a lot just for that, maybe.

Comment: @mikeserv: “just what i [sic] said”? Seriously? “… there are more than matching fields then yours old …” is one step up from gibberish – I hope there’s a typo in there, but I can’t guess what you mean. “handles the problem of the _last_ three matching fields” is only slightly more intelligible. Do you mean that my command will fail for lines that contain “`Val…=…Val…=`”? If so, I guess you’re right; I didn’t consider that case. But there is ***nothing*** in your first comment suggesting that that’s what you’re talking about, and your second comment is still far from clear.

Comment: @mikeserv: Remember, I said, “Note that my approach assumes that the data look at least generally like the illustration in the question.” If you’re going to claim that my solution fails on input that looks radically *different* from the illustration in the question, it behooves you to at least ***give an example*** of input for which my command fails.

Comment: To emulate `cut -d'=' -f2` with `sed` given the data in the question, you need only do: `sed -n 's/[^=]*=//p'`. Your thing, given this sample: `Val = 4 Valerie != Tom Valedictorian != me Valorous = Galahad` prints `Galahad`. `cut` prints `4 Valerie !`. If you wanted to emulate `cut` in *any* case you'd do: `sed 's/=/\n&/2;s/[^=]*=//;/\n/P;d'` which also prints `4 Valerie !` *(though portably you'd need to substitute a \backslash followed by a literal newline for the first occurrence of `\n` in that statement)*.

Comment: Or possibly: `sed '/\n/P;//d;y/=/\n/;//G;s/\(\n\)\n*/\1/g;D'` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/part2/q;s/[^=]*=//p' \
<<\DATA
<Title>
 [part1]
  A.File = a
  A.Val = val1
  B.File = a
  B.Val = val1
 [part2]
  A.File = a1
  A.Val = val2
  B.File = a
  B.Val = val1
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 a
 val1
 a
 val1
```

That should do the trick. It will immediately `q`uit the input file the first time it encounters the string *part2* anywhere in the input. This means that it never even attempts to read through the parts of the file you don't want - which should make it very efficient.

The `-n` disables auto printing so `sed` only prints what it is definitely told to `p`rint. The only time it is ever *definitely* told to print is when it can successfully remove a sequence of 0 or more characters that are not `=` and one character that is an `=`.

If you wanted to print the whole matched line instead you could do:

```
sed -n '/part2/q;/=/p'
```